# Android Swipe ListView Dismiss and Stay

Tags: android, listview, swipe, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to implement a swipe function to my app.
When I swipe to the right or "far right", I want my app to dismiss to element in the list. This code works to dismiss, but the item reappears immidiately. I want it to disappear forever... Additionally I want the background to stay to be able to read the text behind. Then I want it to swipe back to see the original list item.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldDismiss(int position, SwipeDirection direction) {
    return direction == SwipeDirection.DIRECTION_NORMAL_RIGHT || direction == SwipeDirection.DIRECTION_FAR_RIGHT ;
}

@Override
public void onSwipe(int[] positionList, SwipeDirection[] directionList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < positionList.length; i++) {
        SwipeDirection direction = directionList[i];
        int position = positionList[i];
        String dir = "";

        switch (direction) {
            case DIRECTION_FAR_LEFT:
                dir = "Far left";
                break;
            case DIRECTION_NORMAL_LEFT:
                dir = "Left";
                break;
            case DIRECTION_FAR_RIGHT:
                dir = "Far right";
                break;
            case DIRECTION_NORMAL_RIGHT:
                dir = "Right";
                break;
        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

To clarify based on the picture below. How do I remove an item so it disappears forever from the list. Additionally, how do I make the "blue-ish" background stay and be able to swipe back to see the original item?

[image]

I hope you understand what I mean!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You never removed the item from `mAdapter`. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onSwipe(int[] positionList, SwipeDirection[] directionList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < positionList.length; i++) {
        int position = positionList[i];
        SwipeDirection direction = directionList[i];
        if(direction == DIRECTION_FAR_LEFT){
            mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

As for the item swiping and being able to undo it, [this](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo) library seems useful